# Where do I find the Givini smith to forge reshaped Varia's custom weapon?

Tags: the-last-sovereign

[image]

Problem being I can't seem to figure out where he went. I invested the requisite amount of PRoN to fund Givini Smithing, and now I have no idea where to look to find him to start finishing Varia's custom weaponry.

Where do I go?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He can be found in New Givini, in Givino Vinai

[image]

He should be inside on the left.

[image]